# Roaming Profile Alternatives

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-management, user-profile, roaming

I'm a volunteer system admin at a small UK Charity. We currently use Roaming Profiles + Folder Redirection for Desktop, Documents, Downloads & Pictures. We only have around 8x Windows 10 PCs and just over 10 users with 2 Windows Server 2022 servers and run a Local Windows Domain.  We're wanting to replace Roaming Profiles with something more robust - we dont want to disable the 'feature' as users require their browser, windows, ms office and conferencing apps settings roamed between PCs.

FSLogix seemed like an ideal solution (particularly the detailed logs for fault finding) but this doesn't work in an offline scenario and we would like to support laptops working offline out-with the premises. We tried storing one of the CCDLocations on the local drive but once connected to the servers the VHDX's become out of sync.

Can anyone suggest any solutions? High cost and complexity are big deterrents for us due to our size.